# Why isn't Maxout used in the state of the art models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, dropout, activation-function

I have just read the paper from Ian Goodfellow et al. titled ["Maxout Networks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4389.pdf).

It seems that the Maxout activation should be quite powerful, as it can approximate any convex function, i.e. Relu, function that is used in many state-of-the-art models. Also, Maxout, in theory, should work better with dropout than other activation functions.

I am therefore wondering, what is the intuition for using Relu instead of Maxout.

Comment: Not enough bang for your variable-number buck? More variables means more variance. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Agree with @Emre that more variables can lead to overfitting.

Comment: Thanks! So assuming that we have much more data, maxout should work better than relu, because overfitting will not be an issue?

Comment: Perhaps, but is it the best, or even a good use of model complexity? That is the question.